# How to change from localhosting to a domain name?

Tags: node.js, express, server, client, processing

I'm not sure how to make a public server from my laptop or from a domain name bought off of somewhere like Google.

Currently I have followed a tutorial on creating a server that hosts some processing code on localhost:3000 but I wanted to make it public so my friends can connect etc. I've tried using my public ip address as well as my Ipv4 address on my laptop but it seems to only work via LAN connection. I was wondering if I buy a domain name from Google if it is possible to replace 'localhost:3000' with a domain name using Node.js and express.

```
var socket;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600,400);
  background(51);
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

  socket.on('mouse', newDrawing);
}

function newDrawing(data) {
  noStroke();
  fill(255, 0, 100);
  ellipse(data.x, data.y, 20, 20);
}
function mouseDragged() {
  console.log('Sending: ' + mouseX + ',' + mouseY);

  var data = {
    x: mouseX,
    y: mouseY
  } 
  socket.emit('mouse', data);
```

That is a snippet of my Client Side code, let me know if you would like to see the server side as well.

I hope to be able to connect to a server running from my laptop from different networks by replacing the domain name from localhost:3000 to something like myprivateserver.com

Comment: You could simply use heroku or serve your webserver via a http tunnel from ngrok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way as a commenter has already mentioned, is to host your server on a hosting service like heroku. Ngrok is also fine for development purposes but the url is a very long and convoluted string which is not something your friends will be happy typing.

The reason why you can access your server from LAN but not from the internet is due to the way that your internal network works. If you notice, all of your devices connected on the same (WiFi) network share the same public IP address and also have their own private IP in the internal network (usually something along the lines of 192.168.xxx.xxx.). Because the machines are on the same (private/internal) network, they can talk to each other just fine. Things are more complicated though if a machine from the internet tries to reach them.

This is because machines on the internet only 'know' about your public ip address and nothing about your internal network. So when a request reaches your router it is dropped as it is unclear which machine it is supposed to go to. (This is actually a security feature as requests can only initiate from the internal network).

You can however go into your router settings (usually reachable by typing 192.168.0.1 from any browser/machine connected to the LAN ) and find the NAT (Network Address Translation) settings. 
You can then map port 80 - the default http port, although you can use any port you want - of your router to [private-ip-address]:3000 of your computer where [private-ip-adress] is the local IP of the computer hosting the node server (possibly something like 192.168.xxx.xxx).

If everything is done correctly, your server will be reachable from the open internet from anyone who knows your public IP.

Buying a domainname and using it, also requires some additional steps: This is because usually public IPs provided by ISPs to 'home' customers are dynamic and will change from time to time. You will thus need to use a dns service (some free ones exist out there, personally I use  [this](https://www.noip.com/remote-access?gclid=EAIaIQobChMIieTjq5Gx4gIVGfhRCh0zmQiCEAAYASAAEgI1WvD_BwE&utm_campaign=Brand%20International%20google&utm_content=Brand%20International%20Google%20Percent%20Ad&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&utm_term=dyn%20dns) one) in order to make sure that the domainname always points to the correct public IP!

Comment: Thank you so much that was extremely insightful. Especially the noip.com suggestion, I'll definitely try it out. I'm new to networking so your explanation cleared up a lot of things.